# DELL R320 boot with USB disk drive

Tags: ubuntu, boot, dell

I need to boot a DELL R320 server from a USB (3.0) disk drive with Ubuntu 14.04 Server. With a USB pen flash (LiveCD) it boots correctly but with the USB disk it says there is no bootable device.

Using that same disk in a laptop I'm able to boot.

This is odd. Does anybody succeeded to boot with an external USB **disk** drive? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Reboot computer, press F2 to came BIOS. 
Find "Boot Options" 
Enable USB Boot

Save.

Reboot, press F12 key.
Choose USB Drive

Comment: USB was already enabled and the disk was detected. I can could see that the server tried to boot with the external disk but it said there was no bootable device.

Comment: I managed to boot with a different approach: 
- I choose to boot through UEFI, instead of through BIOS. Saved configuration and rebooted.
- Then, during boot time I press F11 to bring the UEFI boot menu
- Then I added a boot option and choose to boot with /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi

This way I'm able to boot with the external drive.

Funny enough, I can use that USB drive to boot on my laptop.